# How to access controls residing in hubsections in onloadstate method

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am unable to access the controls such as textboxes residing in hubsections in `OnLoadState` method of the page.

I want to set the `TEXT` property of textboxes on loading the page. But without access, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Loaded` instead:

```
<HubSection Header="Trailers">
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Loaded="TextBox_Loaded" />
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

And then set the value like below :

```
private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
    txtBox.Text = "Some Text";
}
```

Copied from [here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-xaml-hub-control-getting-started-tutorial-semanticzoom).